# how to get parent key by child value with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have this example json:

```
{
    "Server monitoring - Disk, Memory, CPU": {
        "alerts": {
            "d_usage_65": {
                "title": "D Usage 65 | #site"
            },
            "d_usage_75": {
                "title": "D Usage 75 | #site"
            }
        }
    },
    "Categoty 2": {
        "alerts": {
            "thread_count_50": {
                "title": "Thread Count above 50 | #site"
            },
            "upload_manager_thread_count_100": {
                "title": "Thread Count above 100 | #site"
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get "d_usage_65" for input "D usage 65 | #site".
This is what I have tried:

```
.[] | .alerts | select(.[].title == "D Usage 65 | #aidoc_site") | keys
```

but it returned:

```
[
  "d_usage_65",
  "d_usage_75"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access keys and values at once using `to_entries`. For instance:

```bash
.[] | .alerts | to_entries[] | select(.value.title == "D Usage 65 | #site").key
```

```json
d_usage_65
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nDPLqJqJgk-)

Another approach could be using `tostream`:

```bash
.[] | .alerts | tostream | select(.[1] == "D Usage 65 | #site")[0][0]
```

```json
d_usage_65
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iTieK2yvcXq)

Answer (score 0):

`to_entries` and `select` are the important things here:

```bash
$ jq -r --arg t 'D Usage 65 | #site' '.[].alerts | to_entries[] | select(.value.title==$t) | .key'  example.json
d_usage_65
```